# R: converting dataframe to table

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with three variables named for example `df$V1`, `df$V2`, `df$V3`.
`df$V1` and `df$V2` are both factors, while `df$V3` is numeric.

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = letters[1:4],
  V2 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4),
  V3 = 1:12
)
```

I am looking for a way to create a table that contains the values in `df$V3`, with `df$V1` as the rows, and `df$V2` as the columns.

I tried variations on table, but didn't get anywhere. 
Perhaps someone could help,
Thanks in advance,
Davy.

Comment: This [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/210673) now has a list of the various ways to do this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an alternative to `table`:

```
xtabs(V3 ~ V1 + V2, df)
```

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by ran2, you can use the `reshape` package. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = factor(sample(letters[1:5],100,replace=TRUE)),
                 V2 = factor(toupper(sample(letters[1:5],100,replace=TRUE))),
                 V3 = runif(100))
library(reshape)
cast(df, V1 ~ V2, mean)
```

Comment: See also `reshape2` which is much faster