# create a matrix from data frame

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame with categorical values

```
Names   Dis   Del
    A   0-2   0-2
    A   2-4   0-2
    A   6-8   6-8
    B  8-10  8-10
    C   10+   10+
```

What I want is output in the number of count as per this data

```
       0-2  2-4  6-8  8-10  10+      
 0-2     1                       
 2-4     1                    
 6-8               1           
8-10                     1   
 10+                          1
```

I also want to export this data which was created out of this data frame.

Comment: or `xtabs(data=df,  ~ Dis+Del)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: converting dataframe to table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584383/r-converting-dataframe-to-table)

Comment: @jogo I'm a little bit in doubt about the duplicate. Therefore made a cw-answer from your comments

Answer (score 2):

From the comments of @mtoto & @jogo:

```
table(mydf[-1])
```

or:

```
xtabs(data=mydf, ~ Dis+Del)
```

Both give:

```
      Del
Dis    0-2 10+ 6-8 8-10
  0-2    1   0   0    0
  10+    0   1   0    0
  2-4    1   0   0    0
  6-8    0   0   1    0
  8-10   0   0   0    1
```

If you want to get the levels in the correct order (`10+` as last one):

```
mydf$Dis <- factor(mydf$Dis, levels = c("0-2","2-4","6-8","8-10","10+"))
mydf$Del <- factor(mydf$Del, levels = c("0-2","6-8","8-10","10+"))
```

Now you get:

```
      Del
Dis    0-2 6-8 8-10 10+
  0-2    1   0    0   0
  2-4    1   0    0   0
  6-8    0   1    0   0
  8-10   0   0    1   0
  10+    0   0    0   1
```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- read.table(text="Names   Dis   Del
    A   0-2   0-2
    A   2-4   0-2
    A   6-8   6-8
    B  8-10  8-10
    C   10+   10+", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `dcast` function from the `reshape2` package.

```
df <- data.frame(Dis = c("0-2","2-4", "6-8", "8-10", "10+"),
                 Del = c("0-2", "0-2", "6-8", "8-10", "10+"))
```

Convert the columns you want to reshape by to factors.

```
df$Dis <- as.factor(df$Dis)
df$Del <- as.factor(df$Del)
```

Add a count columnt to reduce:

```
df$counts <- 1
```

Then apply the `dcast` function. We use the two named columns to set us cols/rows of the new matrix. The `fun.aggregate` ensures that if you have multiple occurrences of the same combination then you get the count of the occurrences.
If you want a binary 0/1, then set this to `max`

```
wide_df <- dcast(df,
                  Dis ~ Del,
                  value.var = "counts",
                  fun.aggregate = sum)
```

Here is the result:

```
print(wide_df)
   Dis 0-2 10+ 6-8 8-10
1  0-2   1   0   0    0
2  10+   0   1   0    0
3  2-4   1   0   0    0
4  6-8   0   0   1    0
5 8-10   0   0   0    1
```

To get the same ordering as in your question, you can set the factors in the first step to be ordered with whatever order you desire.

Comment: Or use recommendations of the 2 comments.